# Magento 2 - Adding final price and websites to product collection

Tags: magento, collections, magento2

I am looking to override the standard Magento2 getList() method in \app\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository.php

I've tried $collection->addFinalPrice() and $collection->addMinimalPrice(), however, even when a catalog discount is in place, the full item price is still returned.

If I add $collection->addWebsiteNamesToResult() - nothing happens, I would like add a list of websites to which the product is assigned to the collection - how would I go about this?

Here is a sample of the edited code (for testing purposes only).

```
  public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection);

    foreach ($this->metadataService->getList($this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create())->getItems() as $metadata) {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect($metadata->getAttributeCode());
    }
    $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');


    //Add filters from root filter group to the collection
    foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() as $group) {
        $this->addFilterGroupToCollection($group, $collection);
    }
    /** @var SortOrder $sortOrder */
    foreach ((array)$searchCriteria->getSortOrders() as $sortOrder) {
        $field = $sortOrder->getField();
        $collection->addOrder(
            $field,
            ($sortOrder->getDirection() == SortOrder::SORT_ASC) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'
        );
    }
    //ADDED CODE HERE------------------------------
    $collection->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
    $collection->addFinalPrice();
    $collection->applyFrontendPriceLimitations();
    //END ADDED CODE-----------------------------------

    $collection->setCurPage($searchCriteria->getCurrentPage());
    $collection->setPageSize($searchCriteria->getPageSize());
    $collection->load();

    $searchResult = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
    $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
    $searchResult->setItems($collection->getItems());
    $searchResult->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());
    return $searchResult;
}
```